Text summarization with deep learning
I'm finetuning the Mt5  model on the Arabic part of the Xl-sum data set
For ten epochs and the resulted manipulation model was stored in hugging face library, there were good results on the training and the validation loss as well as the Rouge measure was around 60, but when doing the testing  process, I surprised that the  results is a mixture of Arabic symbols and garbage, and it is not understandable.
i want to know , what is the error

There could be potentially tokens and unexpected arabic characters that can be causing the problem. One suggestion is to remove those characters and clean your input before passing it on to the model. Data Pre Processing and cleaning is one of the important thing to keep in mind. Make sure to use the proper character encoding for arabic language. You also might need to debug it step by step. If you can share the code you are executing and error log. I will be able to help you. Try to adjust maximum_length parameter to 512 and num_beams to 4, use early stopping in the generate function.
Furthmore, It will be nice to have a look at the code.
